# Server-side functionality depending on whether a user "likes" a Facebook page with PHP/JS SDK's

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to execute a mySql database query on my website depending on whether a user has "liked" my Facebook page. I have found a few ways to do this, using the PHP and JS SDK's, namely using the API with /USER_ID/likes/PAGE_ID.

When a user has liked my page, I want to add a value to their data in my database, so I thought of adding a function that is called each time the user visits the site, and if they like it, add value to database and also have a boolean value in there so it doesn't keep adding to the value. However, I guessed this would be waste of calls to the server if this happened every time, so I am not sure how to go about setting this up, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are dealing with huge volumes of users I wouldn't worry about it because a check like that on one row of an indexed mysql table should be very quick (200 milliseconds or less for the entire request over a normal internet connection.).  And if the data you need is stored on the server, then how could you possibly avoid the trip to the server?  Unless you store the data in a cookie.

Comment: Yeah youre right, just wasnt sure if there was an easier/better way, but seems this will do fine :)